# Socket.io with promise or async callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This might be kind of an anti pattern, but what would be the best way to simulate a a `promise callback` when emitting data from client to server using `socket.io`?

For some event I would very much like it to behave like a normal get request so the client send data to the server and the server could reply with a response and then resolve or reject the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to keep track of requests. So I would start with a "global" counter (it does not have to be global, it's enough that it is visible for two functions defined bellow) which will be incremented on each request (and emitted together with it) and a "global" handler namespace. The code may look like that:

```
var COUNTER = 0,
    HANDLERS = {};

var custom_get = function(data, clb) {
    COUNTER++;
    var msg = {id: COUNTER, data: data};
    socket.emit("GET", JSON.stringify(msg));
    HANDLERS[COUNTER] = clb;    
};

socket.on("GET", function(data) {
    var res = JSON.parse(data);
    HANDLERS[res.id](res.data);
    delete HANDLERS[res.id];
});
```

Now you just have to make sure that the server will respond with the same format, i.e. JSON

```
{id:X, data:Y}
```

and will use the same ID for the same request. You can use this code like this:

```
custom_get("test", function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

You can also play with that code adding for example timeouts.

Finally have a look at [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/). It's a proper protocol which is simple and you can easily implement it over WebSocket.

Comment: Nice! I kind of missed the trick with the id property that identifies the calls.

Comment: @JohanNordberg Just so you know: there's another aproach. Whenever you send requests to the server these requests are being sent in some order. You have to ensure that the server will respond in reversed order. This is how you can match request with response. Kind of FIFO. This is actually how HTTP with `keep-alive` works. But it gets complicated on the server side to ensure that responses are in correct order (+ there might be a performance hit when some responses are waiting in queue). I would not advice going that way. The way I've shown you above is a lot easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I'm starting to think that I shouldn't use socket.io for these kind of response-dependent request, but rather find a way to access the socket manager/store on the server from a normal get request. Like, in a chat maybe you'd like to ask the server for a list of members in the room.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did. I created a function that emits a socket command, and then returns a promise. My one caveat is I haven't done a lot with this code yet, so it might need some tweaking. It also requires [Q for its promises/deferreds](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

### Client function definition:

```
var EmitPromise = function( socket, command, data ) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    socket.emit(command, data, function( response ) {

        if( typeof response === "object" ) {

            if( response.success === true ) {

                deferred.resolve(response.data);

            } else {
                if( typeof response.message === "string" ) {
                    deferred.reject( response.message );
                } else {
                    deferred.reject( "The request was not successful." )
                }
            }
        } else {

            deferred.reject( "The response to your request could not be parsed." );
        }

    });

    return deferred.promise.timeout( 30000, "The request took too long to respond." );
}
```

### Client side code to make the call:

```
EmitPromise( socket, "getValue", "username" )
.then(
    function( data ) {

        console.log(data);
        return EmitPromise( socket, "getValue", "anotherValue" );

    }, function( message ) {
        console.log(message);
    }
).then(
    //Chain your commands from here
);
```

### Server side handler

The most important part of this handler is that the second parameter, here named setValueResult must be called with an object that contains a "success" key that holds a true or false value. This was a decision on my part to provide a way to reject the promise in case of some kind of error on the server side.

```
socket.on( 'getValue', function( valueName, setValueResult ) {

    var value = getValue(valueName) //Do something with value here

    if( value ) {
        setValueResult({
            success : success,
            data : value
        });
    } else {
        setValueResult({
            success : success
            message : "Unable to retrieve value"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The current socket.io version 2.1.0 allows sending callback functions to the server:

**Client**

```
socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', (data) => {
  console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
});
```

**Server**

```
socket.on('ferret', (name, callback) => {
  callback('woot');
});
```

You can also create a promise before the emit and resolve it in the client callback function.